# How to Load partial View with a form and apply dataannoation validation using Ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a requirement in which i need to load partial view using ajax.I am able to load partial view but data annonations validation is not firing when submiting partial view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got answer i need to register all the validation after ajax call like below:
  and need to add folowing scripts on layout page

```
   ~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js
   ~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js
   ~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js

    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    data: data,
    cache: false,
    success: function (data)
    {
        $('#' + targetDivId).html(data);
        $('#' + formid).removeData('validator');
        $('#' + formid).removeData('unobtrusiveValidation');
        $('#' + formid).each(function () { $.data($(this)[0], 'validator', false); });         //enable to display the error messages
        $.validator.unobtrusive.parse('#' + formid);
        if (callbackfunc)
            return callbackfunc();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your model has DataAnnotations when passing to the view?

Comment: Yes..My model has dataannotations.

Comment: try to Inspect elements on your partial page.